# Set product visibility on observer at store level before product save

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, product-attribute

I have 2 websites, each of which has 2 stores.

When I create a product from a store(say, Store 1) of a website(say, Website 1), and if I set the websites for this product as Website 1 and Website 2, the product's visibility is set as `catalog, Search` only for the store from which I created it(Store 1). As for the other stores, the visibility is set to `Not Visible Individually`.

I have an observer for `catalog_product_save_before`, in which I want to set this visibility at store level.

Tried this code:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
                    array($productId),
                    array('visibility'=>4),
                    1
                );
```

and it works. But for this, I need to get the productId, which I wont get since the product is not yet saved in my observer function.

How do I set this product visibility for a particular store(say Store 3 of Website 2) to `catalog, Search` in the `catalog_product_save_before` observer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it.

The observer function:

```
public function before_product_save($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $product->setStoreId(1)->setData('visibility', 4);
}
```

where, the store id is 1 and the visibility attribute value 4 refers to `Catalog, Search`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are still saving the object and therefore you do not have an ID yet.

You should get the object (alias product) been saved from the eventData parameter
passed to observer function

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$product = $event->getProduct(); //or take a look var_dump the event data.
```

This will allow you to change the value for visibility before saveing the product.

But from the question is no clear to me if you want to save in the same function/event
the product to be
Catalog, Search on store1 
AND
Not visibile on store2

This cannot be done before the save but only after the object is created.

regards

Comment: I don't understand why this cant be done in the observer function. It's just setting an attribute value, right? I found the answer and have posted below. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I was thinking that setStoreId cannot be called at this stage of saving product, but obviously I'm wrong.